# How to evaluate actors trained in custom environments in rllib (Ray)?

Tags: ray

Following the [SimpleCorridor](https://github.com/ray-project/ray/blob/master/python/ray/rllib/examples/custom_env.py) example I can create my own env and train a model! nice. But when I try to evaluate this trained model, rllib does not recognize my custom env.

How can I evaluate a trained model on a custom environment?

When I use `rllib rollout ...` like its suggested [here](https://ray.readthedocs.io/en/latest/rllib-training.html#evaluating-trained-agents) it does not recognize my env because it's custom one. I was hoping to have a function like `run_experiments` but like `evaluate_experiment` so I can call it on my project inside one of my files.

Thats the issue.
If you want to see my custon_env is this [one](https://github.com/Draichi/cryptocurrency_prediction/blob/master/run_agent.py)

Right now I'm having to copy my environment and paste it inside the `gym/envs/` package directory and register it in the `__init__.py` file.

Would be good to see another way to do this

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can copy the rollout.py script and modify it to register any custom envs or models in the start of the script. That will allow it to work with any envs not on gym already.